# "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." on form disposal

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dispose, invalidoperationexception

"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." appears to be a common error with `foreach` loops, but I can't figure mine out. I have two classes of forms. One is begun on startup, and a button creates new instances of the second form, and displays them. When I **close** the secondary forms, I get an `InvalidOperationException`.

**FirstForm.cs**

```
public partial class FirstForm : Form
{
    SecondForm frmSecond;
    ...
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmSecond= new SecondForm ();
        frmSecond.Show();
    }
}
```

**SecondForm.designer.cs**

```
partial class SecondForm
{
    ...
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing); // InvalidOperationException thrown here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a `PowerPacks.RectangleShape` object I had placed on my second form and forgot about (because it wouldn't render.) I deleted the object, and the form disposed just fine.

Testing this further, I found that any control which requires a `PowerPacks.ShapeContainer` (`LineShape`, `OvalShape`, and `RectangleShape`,) cause this problem, but other `PowerPacks` objects don't.

I'm not sure why this happens, so if anyone figures out a workaround, I'd appreciate that. But for now I'll avoid `PowerPacks` shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that it calls Dispose recursively? Can you have a look at the call stack when the exception occurs?

If this is the case, the broken collection would be the collection of controls on the form

Comment: I'm not sure how I would have broken anything... All I changed was the code seen in `FirstForm`. I feel like this shouldn't break anything...

Answer (score 0):

If you click multiple times, then the reference in FirstForm may no longer point to whatever you are closing.

try

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      var second = new SecondForm();
      second.Show();
 }
```

Comment: Even if I only create a single instance of the second form, it doesn't dispose properly.

Comment: @Hans - oops :) I blame...myself.  The original point stands though.  Code edited.